# Finding the range of the given function

Tags: functions

I am to find the range of the function,
f(x)=1/√x-5

What I have done is:
f(x)=1/√x-5
=>  y=√x-5
=> x-5=1/y²
=> x=(1/y²)+5

In my book the solution is given as, Rf=(0,∞).

But shouldn't the range be R-{0} ?
Because y² ≠ 0 in the denominator, and hence y≠0.

Comment: [How to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I assume you meant to write $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 5}} \implies y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x - 5}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from your book is correct. Note that $y=\frac1{\sqrt{x-5}}\implies y>0$. Therefore, $R_f\subset(0,\infty)$. In fact, $R_f=(0,\infty)$, because if $y\in(0,\infty)$ then\begin{align}y=f(x)&\iff y=\frac1{\sqrt{x-5}}\\&\iff y^2=\frac1{x-5}\text{ (since $y,\sqrt{x-5}\geqslant0$)}\\&\iff x=\frac1{y^2}+5.\end{align}

Comment: oops..I made a terrible mistake in my post, the function was actually f(x)=1/√x-5. Really sorry. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Then the answer from your book is correct. I will edit my answer.

Comment: It is done. What do you think now?

Comment: I see..but is it not true that y≠0 in the denominator, to prevent infinity from creeping in?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Infinity is not a number and therefore it could not possibly creep in.

Comment: I mean to say that if y=0 in the denominator, then wouldn't 1/y result in infinity? And in that case, x will not be real anymore.

Comment: The number $y$ cannot be $0$ simply because the equation $\frac1{\sqrt{x-5}}=0$ has no solutions. And it has no solutions because if $x\leqslant5$, then $\frac1{\sqrt{x-5}}$ is meaningless and if $x>5$, then $\frac1{\sqrt{x-5}}>0$.